# WebSphere Portal class loading

Tags: websphere, portal

i installed a standalone WebSphere portal server, how can I change the class loading policy of the portal server ?

When i log into admin console, i don't have the option to change it.it is blacked out.

Do i have you use jacl scriopts ? Can i

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, WebSphere Portal consist of some applications and services deployed on WAS. Did you tried to change classloader policy of wps.ear? Maybe you have more specific problem? jacl do the same actions as in admin console

Comment: You are correct. However the WAS does have also top level setting. I would strongly recommend against changing it or the class loader settings for IBM provided applications. That is pretty sure way to get into major problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can access Websphere_Portal profile from WAS console and change it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the server *Server Types>WebSphere application servers>WebSphere_Portal* there you can see the *Server-specific Application Settings > Classloader policy* When you select *Single* the *Class loading mode* will be enabled.